# Trying to get CUDA working, sample can't find helper_cuda.h

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, compilation, compiler-errors

I just installed CUDA and have been following http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html

Everything works up until I try to copy a sample code such as deviceQuery to ~/Desktop and compile.

I get the following errors at compile:

```
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64 -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64   -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -o deviceQuery.o -c deviceQuery.cpp
deviceQuery.cpp:23:25: error: helper_cuda.h: No such file or directory
deviceQuery.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
deviceQuery.cpp:111: error: ‘SPRINTF’ was not declared in this scope
deviceQuery.cpp:116: error: ‘_ConvertSMVer2Cores’ was not declared in this scope
deviceQuery.cpp:206: error: ‘checkCudaErrors’ was not declared in this scope
deviceQuery.cpp:230: error: ‘checkCudaErrors’ was not declared in this scope
deviceQuery.cpp:241: error: ‘checkCudaErrors’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [deviceQuery.o] Error 1
```

The code will compile and run in the CUDA directory and it is clear that the compiler can't find helper_cuda.h, I can't find it either does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As indicated by your compile options `-I../../common/inc`, `helper_cuda.h` is located in `$CUDA_HOME/samples/common/inc/`.

If you want to copy the samples to a customized place, you have to copy the whole `samples` dir, or modify some code/compile options to include staff in `common/` dir.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup

> The NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit includes sample programs in source form. You should compile them by changing to ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples and typing make. The resulting binaries will be placed under ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/bin

Just be sure:

`$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}`

`$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`

`$ nvcc -V`

Should show version.

`$ cd ~/some_path/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples`

`$ make`